# What is the file called "Desktop" in the root directory on my Mac?

Tags: memory, filesystems, root

I was sorting through the files on my computer when I noticed a file I didn't put there, which is very large. It seems to have no associated file type (no suffix), and certainly isn't text. It's 8Gb large so I don't know which happens to be the same amount of RAM I have on this mac, so there may be some correlation there.

First, what is it? why is is it so large? can I delete it? is is spying on me..? 0-0

It's in the root directory. More details see in the screenshot below:

[image: Weird file.]

Answer (score 0):

You stated that it is not a text document, though "Kind" is listed as "[TexEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit) Document". If you open a [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)) window (the application is found in /Applications/Utilities), you can use the [file command](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/El_Capitan/man/man1/file.php) to obtain information on files. That command can look for a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) stored in files of some types and, if one is present, identify the file type from that number. You can try the command `file -I /Desktop` (use a capital letter "I") or just `file /Desktop`. What do you see as output?

You should have a file folder named "Desktop" under your home directory. You should see it listed if you issue the command `ls -ld ~/Desktop` - is it there?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,
/Desktop: application/octet-stream; charset=binary